# How can i redirect page JavaScript/PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to redirect page to URL that return from PHP script.
That when user created a post i want to return value of `mysql_insert_id()` for `post_id`.

```
$('input#submitButton').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'newpost.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.replace("http://localhost/?post_id=...");
        }
    });
});
```

I looked here but not found what i want.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: is the value in `data` ? `?post_id="+data`

Comment: not an actual php question. it's more related to jQuery and AJAX. Could you please review your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php script do :

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'id' => $THE_ID
));
```

then here do:

```
$('input#submitButton').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'newpost.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            window.location = "http://localhost/?post_id=" + data.id;            
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: why nothing happened in `success: function(data) { .. }` when it done?

Comment: probably because you got a php or javascript error before. Just open your browser's console and check the response of your post.